# openvpn client certificate error with "unsupported purpose"

Tags: openvpn, openssl, rsa

I was following [this wiki instruction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Easy-RSA) to generate OpenVPN client certificate. This involves:

```
easyrsa gen-req client1 nopass
```

I tried to use this client1 certificate in my OpenVPN setup. The server log show the following logs (note: the IP address changed from public IP to `192.168.0.2` for security reason):

```
192.168.0.2:5570 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.0.2:5570, sid=1e71335b cc13ec8f
192.168.0.2:5570 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unsupported certificate purpose: CN=client1
192.168.0.2:5570 OpenSSL: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
192.168.0.2:5570 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
192.168.0.2:5570 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
192.168.0.2:5570 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
192.168.0.2:5570 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

So the clear error should be this:

```
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unsupported certificate purpose: CN=client1
```

I checked the certificate with this command:

```
openssl x509 -in client1.crt -text -noout -purpose
```

And the **Certificate purposes** section output looks like this:

```
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : No
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No
Netscape SSL server : Yes
Netscape SSL server CA : No
S/MIME signing : No
S/MIME signing CA : No
S/MIME encryption : No
S/MIME encryption CA : No
CRL signing : No
CRL signing CA : No
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : No
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : No
```

My Questions:

1. What is wrong with my client certificate?
2. What should I do to generate the correct certificate?

Comment: `easyrsa gen-req client1 nopass` only creates the certificate request and key (csr and key). You _did_ sign the certificates with _your_ CA, yes?

Comment: Yes. I did sign the certificates.

Comment: It seems you set `nsCertType=server` for your client certificate. `SSL client : No
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No`. Did you change anything from default in easy-rsa? And what version do you use?

Comment: I a only using the default easy-rsa configs in the `/usr/share/easy-rsa` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to enable `nsCertType` is via the easyrsa `vars` file:

```
# Support deprecated "Netscape" extensions? (choices "yes" or "no".) The default
# is "no" to discourage use of deprecated extensions. If you require this
# feature to use with --ns-cert-type, set this to "yes" here. This support
# should be replaced with the more modern --remote-cert-tls feature.  If you do
# not use --ns-cert-type in your configs, it is safe (and recommended) to leave
# this defined to "no".  When set to "yes", server-signed certs get the
# nsCertType=server attribute, and also get any NS_COMMENT defined below in the
# nsComment field.

#set_var EASYRSA_NS_SUPPORT "no"
 set_var EASYRSA_NS_SUPPORT "yes"
```

The resulting certificate has the following purpose:

```
    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
        TLS Web Client Authentication
    X509v3 Key Usage: 
        Digital Signature
    Netscape Comment: 
        Easy-RSA Generated Certificate
    Netscape Cert Type: 
        SSL Client
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The package from my distro (Fedora 27) did not include the vars.example file thus I didn't know about it.

Comment: Where is `set_var EASYRSA_NS_SUPPORT "yes"` expected to be? In the EasyRSA config on CA, or in the EasyRSA config on the OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the default client configuration of [`easy-rsa`](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/tree/v3.0.3) (v3.0.3) is the source of problem. The default content of the file [`x509-types/client`](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/v3.0.3/easyrsa3/x509-types/client) is:

```
# X509 extensions for a client

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
keyUsage = digitalSignature
```

There is no `nsCertType` definition. To fix this, you'd need to change this file (in the easy-rsa copy you're using) and add this line:

```
nsCertType = client
```

Then the same client cert generation command works as a charm.

P.S. Thanks [@lenniey](https://serverfault.com/users/255884/lenniey) for giving me the idea where to check. Thanks [@andrew](https://serverfault.com/users/226242/andrew) for the `openssl` command alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with my client certificate?

The certificates that was generated is not configured with the SSL Client option, so something with the `easy-rsa` configuration is not correct.

> What should I do to generate the correct certificate?

You can try to fix the `easy-rsa` tool, or you can use `openssl` directly. You will need access to the CA signer's key to do this with `openssl`.

`openssl x509 -req -in <path to client csr> -CAkey <path to CA key> -CA <path to CA cert> -CAcreateserial -out client1.pem`

This will create a certificate signed by the CA (required for authentication with OpenVPN) and should also provide usage for the SSL Client and SSL Server options.